# How to find value from HTML?

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I have this code:

```
<a id="US-7" href="javascript:void(0);" class="chooseSizeLink chooseSizeLinkActive" data-size="10" onclick="ProductDetails.changeSizeAffectedLinks(
                                                           '10780559',
                                                           '170,85 USD',
                                                           '125,32 USD',
                                                           '26',
                                                           '45,53 USDsaved!',
                                                           '10',
                                                           '7',
                                                           '15',
                                                           'true',
                                                           'false',
                                                           'false',
                                                           'false',
                                                           'unknown',
                                                           'US-',
                                                           '555088-401');" btattached="true">10</a>
```

I would like to find this value: 10780559
. Is it possible?
I'm trying to do that in python.

Comment: you added python and beautiful soup as tags so you know what they do but you've not included any previous attempts or ideas?

Comment: no ideas on how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Yes, In fact you can even get each of those values inside the onclick attribute to a list. First lets assign that to a variable `html`

```
html="""
<a id="US-7" href="javascript:void(0);" class="chooseSizeLink chooseSizeLinkActive" data-size="10" onclick="ProductDetails.changeSizeAffectedLinks(
                                                           '10780559',
                                                           '170,85 USD',
                                                           '125,32 USD',
                                                           '26',
                                                           '45,53 USDsaved!',
                                                           '10',
                                                           '7',
                                                           '15',
                                                           'true',
                                                           'false',
                                                           'false',
                                                           'false',
                                                           'unknown',
                                                           'US-',
                                                           '555088-401');" btattached="true">10</a>
"""
```

Then we have to get the `onlclick` attribute of the `a` tag. We can then isolate the string within parenthesis, clean it and make a list out of it.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(html,'html5lib')
list_string=re.search('\(([^)]+)', soup.find('a')['onclick']).group(1) #get string within paranthesis
list_string_narrow=' '.join(list_string.split()).replace("'","") #clean the string
list_onlcick=list_string_narrow.split(',') #make it a list
print(list_onlcick)
print(int(list_onlcick[0]))
```

Output

```
['10780559', ' 170', '85 USD', ' 125', '32 USD', ' 26', ' 45', '53 USDsaved!', ' 10', ' 7', ' 15', ' true', ' false', ' false', ' false', ' unknown', ' US-', ' 555088-401']
10780559
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the  element via the "US-7" id. Then the getAttribute to get the onclick attribute. The split is used to separate the string that is obtained from the onclick attribute into the portion inside the parenthesis. The second split is to separate the array of strings and only get the first one. There might be some unnecessary whitespace, so I also remove whitespace and also the quotation marks. Lastly it is converted to a number.

You should try it piece by piece, if you don't understand what's going on.

```
Number(document.getElementById('US-7').getAttribute('onclick').split(/[()]+/)[1].split(',')[0].replace(/\s/g, '').replace(/'/g, ''));
```

Comment: If I understand the question correctly, the OP is asking for a Python solution rather than a JavaScript solution

Comment: The python part wasn't originally apart of the question, I offered a javascript solution because they tagged it with javascript. I'll just leave it up in case it works for them.